# WaitOne() doesnot wait in ManualResetEvent

Tags: c#, winforms

I think its not waiting at run.waitOne();

here while processing the line of code,suppose i want to pause these lines of code by clicking the pause button.It should wait once again i click the same pause to resume same thread.But it doesnot wait at all.Any idea to achieve this?

```
  ManualResetEvent run=new ManualResetEvent(false);
  bool flag=true;

  StartButton_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
   {

       ThreadStart ts=new ThreadStart(startprocess);
       Thread th=new Thread(ts);
       th.Start();
   } 



  private void StartProcess()
     {
            while(true)

         {

               if (parentform != null)
              {
                  TestForm(parentform);
                  parentform = null;
               }

              else
             {
                    if (a[0] == true)
                    {
                        value[0] = method1();//method1 return a double value
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                    if (a[1] == true)
                    {
                        value[1] =method2();
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                    if (a[2] == true)
                    {
                        value[2] = method3();
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                    if (a[3] == true)
                    {
                        value[3] = method4();
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                    if (a[4] == true)
                    {
                        value[4] =method5();
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                    if (a[5] == true)
                    {
                        value[5] = method6();
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }

                    run.WaitOne();  
                    timer1.Stop();
                    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                    string datetime = Convert.ToString(now);
                    database.InsertTest(datetime,value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3], value[4],value[5]);           


            }     
        }

    }

     private void Pausebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            if (flag)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                run.Set();
                flag = false;                      

            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false
                run.Reset();
                flag = true;

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You've got `Reset` and `Set` the wrong way round - you're trying to *make* it wait if it's already wait... otherwise, you're setting the event, saying "Keep going."

I'd also add that relying on the state of the thread is a bad idea - you should keep track of whether or not you're *logically* paused, and set/reset the event accordingly. Otherwise, you've got an awkward situation where two clicks of the button in quick succession *might* pause and then unpause it, or it *might* just pause it twice.